# Did Change Detection Strategy Change in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-changedetection

I am trying to understand the advantage of using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush. So wrote some components in basic example where OnPush stategy might help. 
Stackblits: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stgymt 
App Co html:

```
 <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <button (click)="onClick()">Click</button>
    <button (click)="changeTitle()">Change Title</button>


<app-movies
  [movies]="movies"
></app-movies>
```

App Co ts :

```
title = 'app';
  movies = [];
  count = 0;
  constructor() {
    const movies = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      movies.push({
        title: 'm' + i,
        prop1: 1,
        prop2: 1,
        prop3: 1,
        prop4: 1,
        prop5: 1,
        prop6: 1,
        prop7: 1,
        prop8: 1,
        prop9: 1,
        prop10: 1
      });
    }
    this.movies = movies;
  }
  onClick() {
    const mCopy = this.movies.slice(0);
    mCopy.push({title: '10', elements: [1.9]});
    this.movies = [...mCopy];
    this.count++;
  }
  changeTitle() {
    this.title = `${this.count}`;
    this.count++;
  }
```

Movies Co html:

```
<div *ngFor="let movie of movies">
<app-movie
  [movie] = movie
></app-movie>
</div>
```

and Movie Co html :

```
<p>{{movie.title}}: </p>
<span>{{movie.prop1}}</span>
<span>{{movie.prop2}}</span>
<span>{{movie.prop3}}</span>
<span>{{movie.prop4}}</span>
<span>{{movie.prop5}}</span>
<span>{{movie.prop6}}</span>
<span>{{movie.prop7}}</span>
<span>{{movie.prop8}}</span>
<span>{{movie.prop9}}</span>
<span>{{movie.prop10}}</span>
```

OnDefault strategy ,If I change title by button, the thing I expect is movies component and its children should also run detection mechanism. But they do not run. This is exactly same behavior as OnPush.
I inspected both cases via Performance Monitor in Chrome developer tools and see no performance achievment.
So what is the point of using OnPush strategy ? 
Thanks!

Comment: I expect that every time I change the title bottom, the movie component should re render the data but that does not happen. So what is the purpose of OnPush instead of OnDefault if same behavior.

Comment: I inspected both cases via Performance Monitor in Chrome developer tools and see no performance increment. So could you tell me why I should use OnPush strategy here?.

Comment: You can take a look at: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html for more details about change detection.

Comment: I am following the tutorial in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1uORsKjrMo&t=365s  .Tutorial is Angular 2 based , I run same code but do not see performance decrement using OnDefault. Both strategies are working without delay. Maybe Angular 5 strategy changed so Angular only checks for input elements(movie) change instead of all objects such as title?

Comment: Use a function or getter in your view. Then use the default strategy and see why OnPush is preferred.

Comment: I provided stackblitz. Could you please edit there.

Comment: @yurzui Sorry, I wrongly put OnPush on Movie Component. I removed it and still same behavior. Cannot see perfomance achievment

Comment: @yurzui could you please illustrate situation where I can see performance change in provided stackblitz?

Comment: Try mutating the existing array instead of changing the reference to point to a new array, with OnPush enabled in all components. You'll see what happens (or rather what doesn't) differently than without OnPush.

Comment: OK. Thank you all ! I appreciate.